# problem making a raspberry transparent

Tags: debian, nginx

I have a totem with Android operating system connected to a Raspberry (in DHCP) with Nginx, the Raspberry is connected to the network via Wlan interface. The totems are managed by a VM connected directly to the network. my problem is that when I connect the totems to the raspberry they are no longer identified by the server that manages them. How can I solve it?

Comment: what's a totem?

Comment: totem is like led wall

Comment: It has little to do with debian or nginx. And i do not understand the whole design. Where is the VM? Raspberry should replace it, or just a proxy, or just a secondary control? (in last case, should the RPI connect to VM instead of the totem?) We lack a lot of details

Comment: so, we don't know anything about these devices, we don't know what kind of services they run and what kind of connections they establish. Could you please add all necessary info (if possible including links to resources) to your question? Your audience here has a good notion of Linux, but it has no idea what specifically you're working with!

Comment: no in the rasp berry it only has to provide content to send to the ledwall while the vm that manages it is in another network that manages to ping the raspberry which is connected via wifi interface

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a novice in this world, sorry for being too vague

Comment: being a novice has nothing to do with not describing the system you have. What's a ledwall? How is it connected? We know Linux, assume we know exactly as much about ledwalls as when you meet a stranger on the train. As asker, *you* must explain what you're working with.

Comment: then I have this led wall which inside has an android operating system which is connected via ethernet to a rasp berry in which inside there is a dhcp server in the ethernet interface, so the led wall takes the address from that.the Raspberry wifi interface has an address of 192.168.101.62 and the VM with the server that controls the LED wall is at the address 192.168.105.223.However, the VM is unable to communicate with the LED wall and can only do so if connected directly to the network without the Raspberry.the goal is to connect the ledwall to the server through the RasBerry

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Could you add this to you question by [*editing*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/758835/edit) it please?

Comment: ok,  thanks a lot, I done it